# Docker-CE on centOS 7 can't run containers

Tags: linux, docker, centos, centos7, docker-ce

I have Docker-CE 18.05.0-ce (also tried on 18.03.0).
After installation (used official docs for installation and post-installation) try to run:

```
docker run hello-world
```

It downloads but can't untar because of permissions:
Output from command:

```
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied
```

Output in debug mode:

```
DEBU[2018-06-15T12:50:48] Downloaded 9bb5a5d4561a to tempfile /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob852000141
DEBU[2018-06-15T12:50:48] Start untar layer
DEBU[2018-06-15T12:50:48] Cleaning up layer 5e34eb70d39d9ddbe0512db63ef2bf4811924cffbc5c6ce0a34e9c3b37af5363: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied
```

I've tried to use sudo and change permissions (e.g. 777) for folders in /var/lib/docker

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Some information from docker info:

```
Storage Driver: vfs
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Runtimes: runc
Kernel Version: 4.13.13-5-pve
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

Comment: Vote to close. You should go to SuperUser or ServerFault for this question.

Comment: Have you tried `docker image prune` and `docker container prune`, `docker rmi hello-world:latest` and `docker run hello-world` again?

Comment: I haven't any images and containers because of error. But I've tried commands you specify. Same result on last command.

Comment: I also have tried as root user with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I used CentOS as a virtual machine with **LXC** virtualization.
There is solution how to run Docker in LXC, but didn't try it.
I have changed VM to new one with **KVM** virtualization and now Docker works.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to disk usage. Do you have space in the disk?

```
$ df -h
```

Or inodes exhaustion:

```
$ df -i
```

If you have space and free inodes, then please check your version:

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i docker
docker-common-1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64
docker-1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64
docker-client-1.13.1-53.git774336d.el7.centos.x86_64

# docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 774336d/1.13.1
```

Comment: Yes, I have disk space. Version: 
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40